# Unable to get provider androidx.camera.camera2.impl.Camera2Initializer

Tags: android, android-camerax

My android app crashed while i try to open it, below is its output log :
[image]

My android app is this [repo](https://github.com/RangiLyu/nanodet/tree/main/demo_android_ncnn), and my device is Streaming Rear View Mirror like [this one](https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a230r.1.14.106.2da133b37yKHuA&id=597345031110&ns=1&abbucket=17#detail) whose android api is 22 :

[image]

Comment: Does it work on a typical Android phone? Also I would try to upgrade your CameraX version to the latest. Alpha 05 is a rather old version.

Comment: @Xi张熹 Is there any java version sample code of the lastest camerax for reference ? Because many APIs changeed, i want to know the new implemented APIs.

Comment: You can find CameraX' official code sample here: https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/master/CameraXBasic

Comment: @Xi张熹 that repo seems written in kotlin, then i find a java version camerax 1.0.0-beta05((https://github.com/akhilbattula/android-camerax-java) for reference.

Comment: I installed the 'android-camerax-java' apk on my device, it still says `CameraX initialize() failed` `androidx.camera.core.InitializationException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference`

Comment: What device are you using? Could you try with a different Android phone?

Comment: My device is as above image shows, it is Streaming Rear View Mirror, i have to deploy my app on that device

Comment: Does a regular camera app works on that device? e.g. could you download a camera app from Play Store, and see if it works on your device? Or, you could try https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/master/Camera2Basic and see if it works? I suspect the device has some quirks that are not supported by CameraX. CameraX is aims to support the most common Android phones, and this device is pretty uncommon.

Comment: Camera2Basic app is worse than CameraXBasic,  CameraXBasic app can still be installed, but the Camera2Basic app reports an error during installation, says there was a problem parsing the package. I admit that such device is really fastidious.

Comment: Looks like the CameraX is not compatible with the device. The error you gave means that the camera ID returned by the device is null. Does the device even have a camera? It might be a bug in camera HAL. If you know camera2 well, you might be able to debug the issue.

Comment: Yes, such device is not as common as mobile phone, but i think in the future, such device will become more polular as vehicle electrification evolves. This device actually has 4 cameras : front view, rear view, left view, right view. I installed another app, this app can get camera preview, so it prove the camera function works, but as for camerax, how to make it right ? I am not so familiar with camera development, could you please give me some debug instructions ? Thanks !